# Invoke generic method by type where type is interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, generics

Basically I want to do very simple thing. I want to call generic method, where generic limitation is given by interface - ICollectionEntity.
Here is action from my controller - it's temporary solution for development purposes.

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    protected ICollectionsOrchestration collections;
    public ActionResult Collection(string id)
    {
        var type = collections.GetType(id);

        using (var uow = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
        {
            try
            {
                MethodInfo method = collections.GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(f =>
                    f.Name.Equals("Fetch") && f.GetParameters().Count() == 0);
                MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);

                var data = (IEnumerable<ICollectionEntity>) generic.Invoke(collections, null);
                return View(data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var msg = ex.Message;
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

Here is ICollectionsOrchestration interface and concrete example of ICollectionEntity.

```
public interface ICollectionsOrchestration
{
    Type GetType(string type);
    IEnumerable<T> Fetch<T>() where T : ICollectionEntity;
}

public class Collection : ICollectionEntity { }
public partial class Language : Collection { }
```

But on the line `MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);` I got exception:

> GenericArguments[0], 'Idea.Data.Collections.Language', on 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] FetchT' violates the constraint of type 'T'.

But when I change generic limiation to `Collection` it just works.
So, can you say me why it works with concrete class but not with interface?

Comment: Can you should a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I try to figure out something, give me few minuts...

Comment: I took a shot at making a Fiddle of this, https://dotnetfiddle.net/nBMUBp, but it works. Are you sure your inheritance hierarchy is as you have shown? Can you replace the generic code with code specific to `Language` and have it compile?

Comment: First of all, I'd suggest you replace FirstOrDefault() by Single() (or SingleOrDefault() and check for null). Then, could you also post an example of a concrete class that implements ICollectionsOrchestration? That could be where the problem is, but we can't see that code.

Comment: What is the type that is returned from `GetType(id)` method? did you check whether its of ICollectionEntity?

Comment: It's really seems like an error somewhere in upper application layer, because I wrote short example and it works fine... Anyway, short example is available on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/EHGL51aP) (memory limit on .net fiddler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, I had 2 interfaces `ICollectionEntity` each one in different project inside solution and in HomeController I had using for both project namespaces. Thank you for advices.